# Grant access on ActiveDirectory ServerContainer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, active-directory, wmi

I need to find a way to programmatically grant permissions on a ServerContainer of a default site in Active Directory.

Manually it's simple to do via the "Active Directory Sites and Services":

[image]

And then from the properties one needs to go to here to grant required permissions:

[image]

I have tried to do it via PowerShell, I managed to find the ServersContainer but I cannot find a way to set its permissions. I have browsed lots of stuff on Google but I cannot find a solution.

Anybody has got an idea how to approach it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sites are ADObjects living in `CN=Configuration`, so if you use `Get-ADObject` you can then use `Get-ACL` on that object in the AD PS drive. Which you can then use the methods on that object or the `Set-ACL` cmdlet to alter.

```
$params = @{
    Filter = 'ObjectClass -eq "site" -and name -eq "Default-First-Site-Name"'
    SearchBase = 'CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com'
}
$SiteDN = (Get-ADObject @params).DistinguishedName
$SiteACL = Get-ACL "AD:\$($SiteDN)"
```

Comment: Thank you Ben! This is a right solution. Works like a charm! You are great!